# How to fix this warning: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

When I use the ScrollToTop component in my React app I get this warning in the browser:

> Line 12:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

What change can I make to remove this warning? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: I saw it before and tried to implement the answers but it is not exactly solve the problem with my code, Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `history` to dependency list of the `useEffect()` block:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
  return () => {
    unlisten();
  }
}, [history]); // <- add history here
```

Or you can import `history` instead of passing it as a prop, and then avoid the need to include it in the `useEffect()` dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, [history]);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Add `history` to the array that is the second parameter of the `useEffect` hook function. This is so that whenever `history` changes, `unlisten` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, [history]); // <= you need this

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

API :
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
```

In the example above, we pass [count] as the second argument. What does this mean? If the count is 5, and then our component re-renders with count still equal to 5, React will compare [5] from the previous render and [5] from the next render. Because all items in the array are the same (5 === 5), React would skip the effect. That’s our optimization.